# Trying to get DAY_OF_WEEK from calendar causes Resource Not Found

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find the day of the week by:

```
Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
int dow = cd.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

But whenever I load the program I get a

```
Unable to Start Activity android.content.res.Resources$NotFound Exception: String resource ID #0x5
```

And 0x5 corresponds to Thursday, today, in the Calendar resource I think.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure the error comes from there? If you remove these lines, is the error gone?

Comment: Yes, it is for sure these two lines.

Comment: Instead of those two lines, use `int dow = 5;` and see if the error is still there.

Comment: Nevermind, issue was something else. I feel foolish now

Comment: please share us the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the gen folder or clean the project using: Project-> Clean and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be with calendar? There's other methods out there that doesn't involve the calendar to get the current day of the week..

edit:

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR">
 </uses-permission>
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR">
   </uses-permission>
```

Comment: I would like to use Calendar, but I can also use date I guess.

Comment: could it be that you forgot to add the permissions?? I'll edit my answer with some code.

Comment: The Calendar class has NOTHING to do with the calendar permissions!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update view with that int value which is not true (because setText method isn't overloaded for int type), you need to make array of strings like that

```
private static final String[] WEEK = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
```

and use it

```
textView.setText(WEEK[cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)]);
```